# How to create working properly sequence?

Tags: oracle, plsql, sequence

I create a table, a sequence and a trigger. I add the first record with the correct data. In the ID column I have 1. Then I try to add a record with invalid data, I get an error. Correct error, adds data to table. Unfortunately, the new record has ID = 3. Why is this happening? I would always have consecutive numbers in the ID column, regardless of the number of attempts to enter invalid data.

```
  --CREATING TABLE TEST
CREATE TABLE TEST_TABLE 
   ("ID" NUMBER PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL, 
    "NAME" VARCHAR2(20) NOT NULL,  
    "PERSONAL_ID_NUM" VARCHAR(11) UNIQUE NOT NULL,
     CONSTRAINT "LENGTH_PIN" CHECK (LENGTH(PERSONAL_ID_NUMBER) = 11),
     CONSTRAINT "IS_DIGIT_PIN" CHECK (REGEXP_LIKE(P_PESEL2,'^[0-9]*$'))
     );

--CREATING SEQUENCE
CREATE SEQUENCE SEQ_TEST_TABLE START WITH 1 INCREMENT BY 1 MINVALUE 1 NOMAXVALUE NOCYCLE CACHE 2;

--CREATING TRIGGER
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER TR_TEST_TABLE
BEFORE INSERT ON TEST_TABLE FOR EACH ROW 
BEGIN
SELECT SEQ_TEST_TABLE.NEXTVAL
INTO :new.ID
FROM dual;
END;

--INSERT DATA, VALID VALUES
INSERT INTO TEST_TABLE(ID, NAME, PERSONAL_ID_NUM)
VALUES(SEQ_TEST_TABLE.NEXTVAL, 'JOHN', '12345678901');

--CHECK TABLE
SELECT * FROM TEST_TABLE;

--TRYING INSERT NOT VALID VALUES
INSERT INTO TEST_TABLE(ID, NAME, PERSONAL_ID_NUM)
VALUES(SEQ_TEST_TABLE.NEXTVAL, 'EMIL', '1234567890A');

--INSERT VALID VALUES
INSERT INTO TEST_TABLE(ID, NAME, PERSONAL_ID_NUM)
VALUES(SEQ_TEST_TABLE.NEXTVAL, 'EMIL', '12345678902');

--CHECK TABLE (NEW ROW HAVE ID = 3)
SELECT * FROM TEST_TABLE;
```

Comment: When ID col is Primary Key, why you are filling this with a Sequence value. The trigger executes the Seq value and when it fails the next value is going to be inserted into the table. Do not use Seq for the same. Use only Primary key to achieve this.

Comment: It is almost impossible to have consecutive numbers using sequences - and whatever you think, you do NOT need them in the database! Think about rollbacks - every time you generate next sequence number, but some error happens, that number is lost. So it is perfectly fine to have "holes" in sequence numbers. Once you get to the reporting (or whatever), you can generate numbers in any way you want.

Answer (score 2):

> Unfortunately, the new record has ID = 3. Why is this happening?

You are doing the first insert:

```
INSERT INTO TEST_TABLE(ID, NAME, PERSONAL_ID_NUM)
VALUES(SEQ_TEST_TABLE.NEXTVAL, 'JOHN', '12345678901');
```

It is getting the next value `1` from the sequence and then the trigger runs and replaces the the `ID` value with the next value `2` from the sequence.

Repeat for the next insert and it will get `3` and then the trigger will replace it with `4`. So you are using two sequence values for each insert.

What you want to do is not use the sequence in the original insert and just let the trigger supply that value (or don't use the trigger and just use `SEQ_TEST_TABLE.NEXTVAL` as appropriate in the DML statements - but not both):

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/4f50f/1)

**Oracle 11g R2 Schema Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE TEST_TABLE 
   ("ID" NUMBER PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL, 
    "NAME" VARCHAR2(20) NOT NULL,  
    "PERSONAL_ID_NUM" VARCHAR(11) UNIQUE NOT NULL,
     CONSTRAINT "LENGTH_PIN" CHECK (LENGTH(PERSONAL_ID_NUM) = 11)
     )
/

CREATE SEQUENCE SEQ_TEST_TABLE START WITH 1 INCREMENT BY 1 MINVALUE 1 NOMAXVALUE NOCYCLE CACHE 2
/

--CREATING TRIGGER
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER TR_TEST_TABLE
BEFORE INSERT ON TEST_TABLE FOR EACH ROW 
BEGIN
  :new.ID := SEQ_TEST_TABLE.NEXTVAL;
END;
/

INSERT INTO TEST_TABLE(NAME, PERSONAL_ID_NUM)
VALUES('JOHN', '12345678901')
/

INSERT INTO TEST_TABLE(NAME, PERSONAL_ID_NUM)
VALUES('EMIL', '1234567890A')
/

INSERT INTO TEST_TABLE(NAME, PERSONAL_ID_NUM)
VALUES('EMIL', '12345678902')
/
```

**Query 1**:

```
SELECT * FROM TEST_TABLE
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/4f50f/1/0)**:

```
| ID | NAME | PERSONAL_ID_NUM |
|----|------|-----------------|
|  1 | JOHN |     12345678901 |
|  2 | EMIL |     1234567890A |
|  3 | EMIL |     12345678902 |
```

Comment: You don't need the `select` inside the trigger. `:new.id := SEQ_TEST_TABLE.NEXTVAL` will work just fine

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name True, I had just copied the OP's code and left it unchanged - its now updated to avoid a context-switch.

Comment: @MT0 Thank you. Now it seems so obvious.

Answer (score 0):

From Oracle version 12c Release 1, Identity Column can be used to automatically generate sequence. Check out this document

https://oracle-base.com/articles/12c/identity-columns-in-oracle-12cr1

Basically, the format is (for your table above):

```
CREATE TABLE TEST_TABLE 
  ("ID" NUMBER GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY, 
"NAME" VARCHAR2(20) NOT NULL,  
"PERSONAL_ID_NUM" VARCHAR(11) UNIQUE NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT "TEST_PK" PRIMARY_KEY("ID"),
 CONSTRAINT "LENGTH_PIN" CHECK (LENGTH(PERSONAL_ID_NUMBER) = 11),
 CONSTRAINT "IS_DIGIT_PIN" CHECK (REGEXP_LIKE(P_PESEL2,'^[0-9]*$'))
 );
```

When you insert, you just don't have the id in the values:

```
INSERT INTO TEST_TABLE(NAME, PERSONAL_ID_NUM)
VALUES('JOHN', '12345678901');
```

The document points out the following on the performance of Identity Column

> Not surprisingly, trigger-based test performs much worse than the others. The direct use of a sequence and the 12c identity column give comparable results, which are typically an order of magnitude faster than using a trigger to populate the ID column.

**Note** - and update:

You also mentioned it is important that the ID has no gaps. If this is a hard requirement, then sequence and Identity Column (internally using sequence) do not guarantee that. You can minimize having gaps by having `NO CACHE` to your sequence.

However, to guaratee there are no gaps, you need to use a serialized, thread safe mechanism like

- having a table with a single record (holding last number) that dispenses a number after lock, increment, and then commit part of overall transaction. This, then, would have performance implications, especially if you have long running transactions
- Use a table that holds all IDs (available for use block-by-block), mark as "pending" and then "used" (two updates and a short lock). This also has performance implication dependent on how often an ID is despensed

Comment: In fact. But I assure that in another version of the scaffold was, during the rewriting I had to remove it.

Comment: useful info but does not answer the question.